# Curl POST - time improperly structured

Tags: php, post, curl, time, milliseconds

I'm trying to make a Curl POST to the [BullHorn REST API](http://developer.bullhorn.com/articles/getting_started). First I get an entity and then I try to post it again with some edited parameters.

This works perfectly on my local machine but on the server it doesn't. On the server I get the error **cannot convert value to data type for field dateLastModified** whith type **IMPROPERLY_STRUCTURED_SCALAR**.

On my locale machine the dateLastModified is equal to `1428589472953`. On the staging this is `1.42858947295E+12`. So I've read this could be something to do with the point that is has to be in milliseconds so I've tried to add this:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 250);
```

But this gave the same result ... .

Extra:
I've also had to add the following code because I'm working from a non secure environment (http) and getting data from a secure environment (https) (just for testing).

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE:**

The complete array that I get locally is like this:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 8465
    [address] => stdClass Object
        (
            [address1] => 
            [address2] => 
            [city] => 
            [state] => West-Vlaanderen
            [zip] => 
            [countryID] => 2202
        )

    [businessSectors] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [candidateSource] => 
    [categories] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 2
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [category] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1123135
        )

    [certificationList] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [certifications] => 
    [clientCorporationBlackList] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [clientCorporationWhiteList] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [comments] => Comments
    [companyName] => 
    [companyURL] => 
    [customDate1] => 
    [customDate2] => 
    [customDate3] => 
    [customFloat1] => 
    [customFloat2] => 
    [customFloat3] => 
    [customInt1] => 
    [customInt2] => 
    [customInt3] => 
    [customText1] => 1-3
    [customText10] => 
    [customText11] => 
    [customText12] => 
    [customText13] => 
    [customText14] => 
    [customText15] => 
    [customText16] => 
    [customText17] => 
    [customText18] => 
    [customText19] => 
    [customText2] => 
    [customText20] => 
    [customText3] => 
    [customText4] => 
    [customText5] => 
    [customText6] => 
    [customText7] => 
    [customText8] => 
    [customText9] => 
    [customTextBlock1] => azezaeaz
    [customTextBlock2] => 
    [customTextBlock3] => 
    [customTextBlock4] => 
    [customTextBlock5] => 
    [dateAdded] => 1428589472687
    [dateAvailable] => 
    [dateAvailableEnd] => 
    [dateI9Expiration] => 
    [dateLastComment] => 
    [dateLastModified] => 1428589472953
    [dateNextCall] => 
    [dateOfBirth] => 
    [dayRate] => 0
    [dayRateLow] => 
    [degreeList] => 
    [description] => Resume text.
    [desiredLocations] => 
    [disability] => 
    [educationDegree] => 
    [educations] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [email] => niels14@vroman14.com
    [email2] => 
    [email3] => 
    [employeeType] => Candidate
    [employmentPreference] => Array
        (
            [0] => Permanent
        )

    [ethnicity] => 
    [experience] => 1
    [externalID] => 
    [fax] => 
    [fax2] => 
    [fax3] => 
    [federalAddtionalWitholdingsAmount] => 
    [federalExemptions] => 
    [federalFilingStatus] => 
    [fileAttachments] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [firstName] => niels14
    [gender] => 
    [hourlyRate] => 0
    [hourlyRateLow] => 
    [i9OnFile] => 
    [interviews] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [isDayLightSavings] => 1
    [isDeleted] => 
    [isEditable] => 1
    [isLockedOut] => 
    [lastName] => vroman14
    [linkedPerson] => 
    [localAddtionalWitholdingsAmount] => 
    [localExemptions] => 
    [localFilingStatus] => 
    [localTaxCode] => 
    [massMailOptOut] => 
    [masterUserID] => 
    [middleName] => 
    [migrateGUID] => 
    [mobile] => 
    [name] => niels14 vroman14
    [namePrefix] => 
    [nameSuffix] => 
    [nickName] => 
    [notes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [numCategories] => 0
    [numOwners] => 0
    [occupation] => 
    [owner] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2270
            [firstName] => Webdeveloper
            [lastName] => API
        )

    [pager] => 
    [paperWorkOnFile] => 
    [password] => abc
    [personSubtype] => Candidate
    [phone] => 
    [phone2] => 
    [phone3] => 
    [placements] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [preferredContact] => Phone
    [primarySkills] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [recentClientList] => 
    [references] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [referredBy] => 
    [referredByPerson] => 
    [salary] => 0
    [salaryLow] => 
    [secondaryAddress] => stdClass Object
        (
            [address1] => 
            [address2] => 
            [city] => 
            [state] => 
            [zip] => 
            [countryID] => 1
        )

    [secondaryOwners] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [secondarySkills] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [sendouts] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [skillSet] => 
    [smsOptIn] => 
    [source] => 
    [specialties] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [ssn] => 
    [stateAddtionalWitholdingsAmount] => 
    [stateExemptions] => 
    [stateFilingStatus] => 
    [status] => Subscribed
    [submissions] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [tasks] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [taxID] => 
    [taxState] => 
    [tearsheets] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [timeZoneOffsetEST] => 0
    [travelLimit] => 0
    [travelMethod] => 
    [type] => 
    [userType] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 35
        )

    [username] => niels14
    [veteran] => 
    [webResponses] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [willRelocate] => 
    [workAuthorized] => 1
    [workHistories] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total] => 0
            [data] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [workPhone] => 
    [_score] => 12.096912
)
```

As you can see there is the key **dateLastModified**. This is locally, so as said on the server this show different (so above).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem has to do with curl.

You must have an array in your code using `dateLastModified` as an index value.

There is a data typing issue with this variable causing the error you are receiving.

Comment: I have an array with the index dateLastModified. That's not the problem. I've updated my topic with the array that I get and post.

Comment: How do you think I knew you used dateLastModified as an index before you posted the update?  Somewhere in your code dateLastModified is being used for another purpose or altered.  That is your problem.  It is NOT curl.

Comment: Are you still sticking with "That's not the problem"?  Find the other dateLastModified or rename this dateLastModified.